# Type checking with generics

Tags: java, generics

Here's an illustrational class:

```
class TypeChecker<T> {
    boolean isGood(Object something) {

        // won't compile
        return (something instanceof T);


        // maybe works, but oh so ugly!
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T tmp = ((T) something);
        }catch(ClassCastException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there any nice way to do this?

The particular purpose is a bit different than in the example, but the idea is the same - to check if a variable of type T (parameter) can hold certain object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Class#isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
class TypeChecker<T> {
    private Class<T> ofType;

    TypeChecker(Class<T> ofType) {
        this.ofType = ofType;
    }

    boolean isGood(Object obj) {
        return ofType.isInstance(obj);
    }
}
```

Or just use the `Class` instead of making a wrapper object around it if all you need is the `isInstance` check.

There is not another way to perform run-time type checking dynamically. You must use a `Class`.

`isInstance` has the same semantics as `instanceof` (except that the left and right hand sides are flipped) so

```
"hello world" instanceof String
String.class.isInstance("hello world")
```

both are true.

Also, your 'maybe works' snippet, no that does not work. Generics are erased so unchecked casts do not happen at run-time. That is why they are unchecked. The ClassCastException will never throw. Using exceptions to determine logical flow is not good to begin with.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try.