# Java Generic Conversion from Legacy Code to Generic

Tags: java, generics

How do I convert a legacy enumeration to a 'generic' enumeration?  I want to ensure that the type of every element in the enumeration is correct.  I want to ensure there are no runtime casting errors further in code, especially when I'm not catching them.

Here is my sample code.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

public class TestEnumerationCast {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestEnumerationCast();
}

{
    Vector stringVector = new Vector();
    stringVector.add("A");
    stringVector.add("B");
    stringVector.add("C");
    stringVector.add(new Integer(1));

    Enumeration<String> enumerationString = castEnumeration(stringVector.elements());
    while (enumerationString.hasMoreElements()) {
        String stringToPrint = enumerationString.nextElement();
        System.out.println(stringToPrint);
    }

}

private <T> Enumeration<T> castEnumeration(Enumeration<?> elements) {
    Vector<T> converstionVector = new Vector<T>();
    while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
            converstionVector.add((T) elements.nextElement());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return converstionVector.elements();
}
```

}

I would think that the method castEnumeration would 'convert' the legacy code to the generic code for any type .  Simply stated, I iterate through each element, attempting to cast it to (T).  If this fails, I throw a run-time exception, but only skip the element.  I then have an enumeration of only type .  However, the line to add the type to the vector is not catching the integer.  I'm still getting a runtime exception in the string conversion for the last element, an integer.

I know that I can straight cast to generic type, ignore errors, etc.  All are valid methods.  But I want to be sure that I won't get a runtime exception when I'm not looking for it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, found it!  You have to specify the class you want to utilize in the casting as a method parameter, and then use the .cast(obj) method.

Change the call from

```
private <T> Enumeration<T> castEnumeration(Enumeration<?> elements) {
    Vector<T> converstionVector = new Vector<T>();
    while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
            converstionVector.add((T) elements.nextElement());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return converstionVector.elements();
}
```

to

```
private <T> Enumeration<T> castEnumeration(Enumeration<?> elements, Class<T> tClass) {
    Vector<T> converstionVector = new Vector<T>();
    while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
            converstionVector.add(tClass.cast(elements.nextElement()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return converstionVector.elements();
}
```

And also change the call of the method from

```
Enumeration<String> enumerationString = castEnumeration(stringVector.elements());
```

to

```
Enumeration<String> enumerationString = castEnumeration(stringVector.elements(), String.class);
```

So in total, the code now looks like.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

public class TestEnumerationCast {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestEnumerationCast();
}

{
    Vector stringVector = new Vector();
    stringVector.add("A");
    stringVector.add("B");
    stringVector.add("C");
    stringVector.add(new Integer(1));

    Enumeration<String> enumerationString2 = castEnumeration(stringVector.elements(), String.class);
    while (enumerationString2.hasMoreElements()) {
        String stringToPrint = enumerationString2.nextElement();
        System.out.println(stringToPrint);
    }

}

private <T> Enumeration<T> castEnumeration(Enumeration<?> elements, Class<T> tClass) {
    Vector<T> converstionVector = new Vector<T>();
    while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
            converstionVector.add(tClass.cast(elements.nextElement()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return converstionVector.elements();
}

}
```

Comment: You can also use the Class object to avoid the exception altogether with e.g. [`isInstance`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22733554/2891664). Using the Class to perform the cast was necessary because of type erasure.